# basic radio program input struggle

Tags: python, class, oop

i have been at this for hours trying to figure out what to do. I cannot seem to figure out how to process user input so that instance variable is activated and returns a station.

```
class Radio:

    def __init__(self):
        self.stations = ["STATIC", "97.2", "99.6", "101.7", "105.3", "108.5"]
        self.station_index = 0

    def seekNext(self):
        self.station_index = (self.station_index + 1) % len(self.stations)
        return self.station_index

    def longPressPreset1(self):
        self.progamStation1 = self.stations[self.station_index]

    def longPressPreset2(self):
        self.programStation2 = self.stations[self.station_index]

    def longPressPreset3(self):
        self.programStation3 = self.stations[self.station_index]

    def shortPressPreset1(self):
        self.programStaion1

    def shortPressPreset2(self):
        self.programStation2

    def shortPressPreset3(self):
        self.programStation3

    def displayLCD(self):
        print("Currently Tuned:",self.station_index)
        print("present1:", self.programStation1)
        print("present2:", self.programStation2)
        print("present3:", self.programStation3)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Currently Tuned:", str(self.station_index)


def main():
    myradio = Radio()
    print(myradio)
    displayMenuGetOption()

def displayMenuGetOption():
    print("1 = Display tuned in staion")
    print("2 = Program present station 1")
    print("3 = Program present station 2")
    print("4 = Program present station 3")
    print("5 = Seek next station")
    print("6 = Tune preset station 1")
    print("7 = Tune preset station 2")
    print("8 = Tune preset station 3")
    print("9 = Dump Programming")
    print("10 = Turn off radio")
    option = input("\nEnter option:")

 main()
```

i was thinking about using if logic, but i think that it will make the code more complicated. something i noticed when i tried to return currently Tuned station i got 0 instead of Static. The output should be currently tuned: STATIC. I just want help figuring out how i would go about getting user input match and activate the instance variable in the class.

Comment: I'm guessing either shortPressPreset1(self) returns something or asssigns that to current but it does neither

Comment: it should return what was saved in longPressPresent2(self)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'Currently tuned: %s' % self.stations[self.station_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

- `print("Currently Tuned:", self.station_index)` prints the index of the current station, not the name. You probably want `print("Currently Tuned:", self.stations[self.station_index])`
- `return "Currently Tuned:", str(self.station_index)` does not return a string. You probably want `return "Currently Tuned: {}".format(self.stations[self.station_index]))`
- The line `self.programStaion1` in `shortPressPreset1` doesn't do anything. You probably want `return self.programStation1` or `return self.stations[self.programStation1]` (btw: typo). Same for the other two `shortPressPreset` methods.
- You don't initialize `programStation1` etc. in `__init__`. If `shortPressPreset1` or `displayLCD` is called before `longPressPreset1` the object has no member `programStation1` and an exception is raised.

If you don't want to process the user input with `if` statements, you could handle it with a dictionary:

```
actions = {
    '1': radio.displayLCD,
    '2': radio.longPressPreset1,
    '5': radio.seekNext,
    # ...
}
actions[option]()
```

Comment: if i go about this with the dictionary it would be in the displayMenuGetOption()

Comment: You could make ``displayMenuGetOption`` accept a parameter ``radio`` or ``return option``. Wherever you act upon the input you will need access to this input and to the radio instance.